# Build by changeset date

Tags: tfs, build

I'm new to the TFS Build and I'm wondering if I can include in my manual build only those change sets which are not later than date such-n-such.

The general task I'm trying to solve is to build a past release which I did a frozen on date, say, March 1st and omit a recent changes. No branching I do with my project.

Maybe there is a better way to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it when you queue the build.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no changeset date concept in TFS expect the creation date of changesets  on the same day. Usually we queue a build from a specific changeset in TFS.

You can achieve it by specify the changeset info in **Source Version** of queue build dialog such as `C8` which will build changeset 8. More detail explanation please see below screeshot.

***Note: This function is released with TFS2015 update2 for vNext build.*** To use it, you have to [upgrade to Update2](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/tfs2015-update2-vs) or above.

[image]

You could also build a **label**, how to create take a look at: [Use labels to take a snapshot of your files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/use-labels-take-snapshot-your-files?view=vsts)